# Taking a screenshot with Puppeteer headless chrome before page load ends

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to try and scrape an image off a live cctv stream at an address like: 192.168.1.1/display_pic.cgi?cam=6&res=low

The issue is that the page is continuously loading as it is a live stream.

Puppeteer eventually errors as a timeout when you load the page. Is there a way to get round this, force a screenshot and then close the page?

An example stream is here http://74.95.30.43/display_pic.cgi?cam=1&res=low

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the timeout exception in catch block and then proceed to take screenshot. Here I have used `domcontentloaded` instead of `networkidle` as the server is still serving the client. Sample code: -

```javascript
await page.goto(pageUrl, { waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded'], timeout: testTimeout }).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply not await for the page to be finished loading. That's what I do to investigate flash of unstyled content problems that appear before the DOM has fully loaded.